# Show that a function is continuous problem with denominator

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Show $\frac{x}{x+3}$ is continuous at each $a \neq 3$.  This would be extremely easy if we were allowed to use the ratio bar of functions but the problem specifically prohibits it.

We're thinking of dividing the cases into

$|x|> |x_0 +\delta|  $ or $|x_0 -\delta| > 0 $ and then try to get something to fit $|x + 3| > ? > 0|$ but coming up short.  Any advice or places to look.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\ne-3$, the denominator is removed from zero. Concretely, if $|x_0+3|>c$, then for any $x$ such that $|x-x_0|<c/2$ we have $$\left|\frac{x}{x+3}-\frac{x_0}{x_0+3}\right|
=\left|\frac{3x-3x_0}{(x_0+3)(x+3)} \right|
\leq\frac3c\,\frac2c\,|x-x_0|.
$$
The estimate I used is
$$
|x+3|=|x_0+3+x-x_0|\geq|x_0+3|-|x-x_0|\geq c-\frac c2=\frac c2.
$$

Comment: Can you explain the triangle inequality you used?  Specifically $|x_0 + 3 + x - x_0| $ is greater than or equal to $|x_0 + 3| - |x - x_0|$ Im confused how the minus sign still holds

Comment: It's just the triangle inequality. You have $$|a|=|a-b+b|\leq|a-b|+|b|,$$ so $|a-b|\geq|a|-|b|.$

Comment: Oh my goodness I forgot about that one, I'll try to update later with my finalized proof from this thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
\left\lvert \frac{x}{x+3} - \frac{y}{y +3} \right\rvert = 3 \left\lvert \frac{1}{x+3} - \frac{1}{y+3} \right\rvert
$$
for $x,y \neq -3$.